# vagrant up fails on windows with box_add: undefined

Tags: vagrant

I've spent a few hours now without achieving any outcome trying to vagrant up a box of mine. It works perfectly on my mac and two of my coworkers mac but when trying to `vagrant up` that box on my windows desktop I get an error like this:

```
INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x5583d8>
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:358:in `box_add': undefined
method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The full error log can be found here:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f227b9fb37aae643d276#file-vagrantuperror

Hope you guys can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have both `box` and `box_url` set in your `Vagrantfile`, for example:

```
config.vm.box = "centos65"
config.vm.box_url = "http://www.lyricalsoftware.com/downloads/centos65.box"
```

This solved this problem for me.

Comment: This may not help anyone ever, but just in case Googles led you here, I had a loose comma at the end of the `box_url` line and removing it fixed this exact issue. Whoops.